# Remove blank page between list of figures and list of tables

Tags: table-of-contents, page-breaking, double-sided

Please how can I delete the blank page between List of Figures and List of Tables?

I tried this:

```
\listoffigures 
\nopagebreak[0] 
\listoftables
```

but nothing changed. Here is my code:

```
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents 
\nopagebreak[0]
\backmatter 
\listoffigures \nopagebreak[0] \listoftables
\newpage
\clearpage{\pagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}
\mainmatter
\include{Introduction}
\end{document}
```

I just want to delete the white page between `\listoffigures` and `\listoftables`.

Comment: Use `{\listoffigures\let\clearpage\relax\listoftables}`

Comment: It can be duplicated but if you use a KOMA-class the option `listof=leveldown` will be helpful.

Comment: i want each table in distinct page

Comment: The question was closed as possible duplicated. If the linked question doesn't help we can reopen your question. But it's important to provide a full minimal working example that shows your document class.

Comment: Please why you have closed the question, its not the same: How to show \listoffigures and \listoftables on one page and in the toc?

Comment: It would be opened again if you can give a small example starting from `\documentclass{...} .... \end{document}` otherwise we can't help and the current question is the same with the link.

Comment: tableofcontents 
\nopagebreak[0]
\backmatter 
\listoffigures \nopagebreak[0] \listoftables
\newpage
\clearpage{\pagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}
\mainmatter
\include{Introduction}

Comment: What exactly is the question? Have you tried the solution given in the linked question? What behaviour are you getting, and what would you like instead?

Comment: @researcher: This is contradictory. Your question states that you want to remove the page break between `\listoffigures` and `\listoftables`. Then you comment that you want "each table in distinct page", which seems the opposite.

Comment: i have in my document 3 figures, the listoffigures takes two pages, one of them white page, how can i delete the white page

Comment: i'm still beginner with latex, i want just delete the white page after \listoffigures and \listoftables (no double page as you say)

Comment: Ok, so you do not want `\listoftables` to start a new double page even though you are using a `twoside` layout like `book`. Please edit your question so this is becoming clear! Furthermore, your example code must contain the `\documentclass` declaration so people can understand what's going on.

Comment: Strangely, this is not a duplicate, though the solution is almost identical: `{\listoffigures \let\cleardoublepage\clearpage \listoftables}`.

Comment: @StephanLehmke Make that an answer, please.

Comment: @lockstep Will do, but I have to go right now. Furthermore, I think the question needs a little more editing to properly reflect the request.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I assume you are using a documentclass like `book` which implicitly contains the option `openright` as default, which in turn makes every chapter (and everything like a chapter, i.e. `\listoffigures`) start on a right page.

The command `\cleardoublepage` which is used internally will insert an empty page if neccessary to start a new right page.

### On `\nopagebreak[0]`

`\nopagebreak` is not a very useful command in  LaTeX. Don't use it; it will make your document markup inelegant.

Incidentally, the version `\nopagebreak[0]` you've been using has almost no effect at all; it might even create a new page breaking possibility where none used to be before.

But even the strongest version `\nopagebreak` (without option) would have no effect here as it can't counteract the explicit `\cleardoublepage` used to insert the blank page.

### No blank pages

If you never want a blank page inserted in front of a chapter(-like thing) to make it start in a right page, the answer is easy: Add the option `openany` to the book class like this:

```
\documentclass[openany]{book}
```

### Avoid blank page only for `\listoffigures`/`\listoftables`

If you want to avoid the inserting of blank pages only for `\listoffigures` and `\listoftables`, you can achieve this by locally redefining `\cleardoublepage` to just mean `\clearpage`:

```
{\listoffigures \let\cleardoublepage\clearpage \listoftables}
```

Comment: Really helpful - also works in tufte-book documentclass too...

Comment: @Stephan I am having the same problem, but mine is not due to the page break rule. I have two pages for list of figures while only one is filled with items. If I add one figure to figures of my report then that new figure caption is added to the 2nd page of list of figures. If I remove one figure the 2nd page will be removed. Would you mind helping me solve the problem?