# How to remove the empty page that is placed after the ToC, List of figures and List of tables

Tags: table-of-contents

I've placed a Toc, LoF, and an LoT but, for some reason, there is always an empty page placed after each one and I want to remove said page. How do I do that?

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\graphicspath{ {figures/} }
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\fancyhead[ER]{\nouppercase\leftmark}
\fancyhead[OR]{\nouppercase\rightmark}
\fancyhead[ER,OR]{\thepage}


%opening
\title{MWE}
\author{A1}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{intro 1}
\lipsum

\section {intro 2}
\lipsum 

\makeatletter
\tableofcontents
{\listoffigures
\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage 
\listoftables}
\chapter{Introduction}
\section{Introduction}
\subsection{Something1}
\lipsum 

\subsection{Motivation}
\lipsum 

\subsection{Something 2}
\lipsum 

\end{document}
```

**Edit 1:**
Edit 1: Thanks to a reply posted, I managed to remove the page between the LoF and the LoT but the page between the ToC and LoF still remains

Comment: Related: [Remove blank page between list of figures and list of tables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/69184/134144)

Comment: @leandriis thnx that took care of one of the issues

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your code are several issues:

1. You loaded a lot of packages not related to this issue. I deleted them in the following mwe.
2. Commands like `\tableofcontents` and `\chapter` uses command `\cleardoublepage` internally. To get rid of that one possibility is to localy redefine `cleardoublepage`. See the following code snippet to do that (please see that I included the first chapter!):

   ```
   {\tableofcontents % <===================================================
   \let\cleardoublepage\clearpage % <======================================
   \listoffigures
   \listoftables
   \chapter{Introduction}} % <=============================================
   ```
3. In your table of contents you get bad numbered sections (because an first chapter is missing!) `0.1 Intro 1`. To get rid of that use `\section*{}` instead `\section{}` ...

Please see the following mwe

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[ER]{\nouppercase\leftmark}
\fancyhead[OR]{\nouppercase\rightmark}
\fancyhead[ER,OR]{\thepage}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}

%opening
\title{MWE}
\author{A1}


\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section*{intro 1} % <==================================================
\lipsum

\section*{intro 2} % <==================================================
\lipsum 

{\tableofcontents % <===================================================
\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage % <======================================
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\chapter{Introduction}} % <=============================================
\section{Introduction}
\subsection{Something1}
\lipsum 
\subsection{Motivation}
\lipsum 
\subsection{Something 2}
\lipsum 
\chapter{Test}
\end{document}
```

and its result:

[image: resulting toc]

and

[image: resulting lof lot]

and

[image: resulting chapter one]

Comment: yeah, I knew that I had left some packages there that were irrelevant to recreating my issue but I didn't know which packages to were unnecessary soi just left them. it isn't an issue though since the issues weren't due to the packages used. Thanks for your well-articulated response though, really helped.

Answer (score 2):

You can switch between openany and openright by setting a boolean:

```
\documentclass{book}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\graphicspath{ {figures/} }
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\fancyhead[ER]{\nouppercase\leftmark}
\fancyhead[OR]{\nouppercase\rightmark}
\fancyhead[ER,OR]{\thepage}


%opening
\title{MWE}
\author{A1}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{intro 1}
\lipsum

\section {intro 2}
\lipsum

\makeatletter\@openrightfalse\makeatother %<-- openany
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\makeatletter\@openrighttrue\makeatother  %<-- openright
\chapter{Introduction}
\section{Introduction}
\subsection{Something1}
\lipsum

\subsection{Motivation}
\lipsum

\subsection{Something 2}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

i added the following lines

```
{\tableofcontents
\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage 
\listoffigures
\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage 
\listoftables}
\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage
```

instead of:

```
\tableofcontents
{\listoffigures
\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage 
\listoftables}
```

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/172884)

Comment: @Zarko I'm not adding additional information. this is exactly what I did to solve the issue I had in my initial post. so this, for all intents and purposes, an answer.