# Removing blank page between list of figures and list of tables

Tags: blank-page

i am using document class book. I have tried openany, oneside, cleardoublepage 
But the blank page is not removed between two lists. My lists are quite lengthy though

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove blank page between list of figures and list of tables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69184/remove-blank-page-between-list-of-figures-and-list-of-tables)

Answer (score 1):

This works for me.

```
% loftprob.tex  SE 527980

\documentclass[openany,oneside]{book}

\begin{document}
\listoffigures

\listoftables

\chapter{One}

\begin{figure}
\centering
FIGURE
\caption{A figure}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{A table}
TABLE
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Remember that `\cleardoublepage` if called on an odd page will produce a blank page before the next odd page.